# Как исполнять python код из Sublime 3 в cmd

Tags: python, sublime-text-3

Суть задачи такова. Нужно чтобы при нажатии Ctrl+b в Sublime text 3 вылетало окно cmd и в нем запускался питоновский файл, как если бы я вручную ввел "cd <директория>", а потом "python file_name.py"

Буду рад ссылкам или готовому коду.

Answer (score 0):

Поставь галочку
Tools -> Build System -> Python.
Затем CTRL + b

Comment: Вы меня не правильно поняли, я хочу чтобы программа исполнялась в командной строке винды и там же выводилась, а не собственной строке саблайма, там просто не возможен даже обычный ввод через input()

Comment: В интернете есть предложения поставить Sublime.REPL.
Но как сказали выше ставь VS Code.